# How do I pass command-line arguments to script executed from stdin

Tags: dash-shell

These work fine:

```
/bin/dash xyz.sh arg1
curl | /bin/dash -
```

---

Use case:

```
curl | sh - arg1
```

Ubuntu executes this as:

```
curl | /bin/dash - arg1
```

this fails with: `sh: 0: Can't open arg1`

How do I pass arg1 to `curl | /bin/dash`?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a lark, to pass e.g. the `localhost localhost` arguments
to `curl` as requested:

```
echo curl --head '"$@"' | sh -s localhost localhost
```